# JSF Required Field only call message if i leave them

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with the JSF validation. I have the following form - only the first inputfield is required. So if I leave them empty and click on the primefaces calendar field - JSF render the whole form and of course I got a message that the field is required.

So I need a solutions that the field only call the blur event or required message when I leave the field not when I click another field etc.

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" />
    <b:panelGrid col-spans="4,8" columns="2" id="inputPanel">
        <h:outputLabel value="ID*"></h:outputLabel>
        <b:inputText value="#{managedBean.avsId}" required="true"
                            update="msg" onblur="ajax:managedBean.checkDublicates()"></b:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel value="Legal Form"></h:outputLabel>
        <b:switch animate="true" on-text="natural" offColor="danger"
                            onColor="success" off-text="forensic"
                            value="#{managedBean.legalform}">
        </b:switch>
        <h:outputLabel value="Date"></h:outputLabel>
        <p:calendar value="#{managedBean.date}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy">
            <f:converter converterId="timestampConverter" />
        </p:calendar>
        <h:outputLabel value="Note" style="margin-top:5%;"></h:outputLabel>
            <b:inputTextarea style="margin-top:5%;"
                            value="#{managedBean.note}"></b:inputTextarea>
    </b:panelGrid>
    <b:commandButton value="apply" look="success"
                        style="width:100%;" action="#{managedBean.create()}"
                        update="@form" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: basically, when you click another field the blur event occurs, best thing in your situation would be to fire the validation when pressing the `Tab` button, but i am not sure if this is what you want

Comment: I'm not sure about behaviour of `<b:inputText>` component as I've never used it (is it BootFaces ??). However with usage of `<h:inputText>` you could do this with the same way, but no required field will be marked as invalid until you press the commandButton. It is natural that the method onblur will be invoked when you leave inputText and click <p:calendar> component. Why would you like to achieve such a feature ? Validation on blur event, but not when focus is moved to Calendar ? What is a purpose of that ?